# Coloring edges on graph in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to color an edge of graph in Wolfram Mathematica using color function, that depends on coordinate on the edge? Like using ColorFunction option in Plot[].

I have a function specified on the edge of the graph, depending on coordinate at the edge.
Is it possible to paint a dencity of this function on the edge?
Thanks for responce.

PS: The first idea - to use Inset[] to plug in graphical colored object in EdgeRenderingFunction, but it seems to be quite unnatural. Is there any simpliar ways?

Comment: Please consider posting your MMA-related questions on the dedicated  [Mathematica-SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site for more/better/faster answers.

Comment: The problem is that function, that could be used in EdgeShapeFunction/EdgeRenderingFunction takes just the coordinates of vetices as arguments, so we can't set the Hue[] depending on coordinate on the edge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to use `ColorFunction` to color edges in a Graph is:

```
  ClearAll[colorededge];
  colorededge[pts_, colorfunc_: Function[{x, y}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][y]]] := 
  ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> colorfunc, ColorFunctionScaling -> True];
  edgshpfnc = (If[Last[#2] == "B", First@colorededge[#1], 
  First@colorededge[#1, Function[{x, y}, Blend[{Yellow, Red}, x]]]] &);
  Graph[{"A" -> "B", "B" -> "C", "C" -> "A"}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {"A" -> {0, 0}, "B" -> {1, 1}, "C" -> {2, 0}}, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> edgshpfnc, VertexLabels -> "Name",  ImagePadding -> 10]
```

gives

[image]

and

```
 GraphPlot[{"A" -> "B", "B" -> "C", "C" -> "A"},
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> edgshpfnc, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

gives

[image]